# Why is accessing paragraphs slow? Is there a better approach?

Tags: 8, entities, paragraphs

I'm trying to get the target_revision_id of a paragraph within a paragraph within a node. I can do this, but it is slow.

```
$all_nodes = db_select('node','e')->fields('e',array('nid'));
$all_nodes->condition('type','author');
$data = $all_nodes->execute();
$the_result = $data->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach ($the_result as $node){
    $node_load =  \Drupal\node\Entity\Node::load($node['nid']);
    foreach ($node_load->field_paragraphs as $item) {
      $para_id = $item->entity->field_affiliation_details->target_revision_id;
      //then, store the para_ids in some array
      $para_ids[] = $para_id;
    }
}
```

Performing the reference "$item->entity" makes my app slow down by a lot. It is really just Kilobytes of data. Is there maybe a better approach to this?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You're fetching all the nodes with db_select, a better approach would be to fetch only the node that is currently viewed.

Comment: I need to load and display information about each node so I'm loading them all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well after fiddling around with it some more, I suppose the best answer here is to just cache the variable  `$para_ids` using `\Drupal::cache()` and then update it whenever there is a node/entity update or insert. I could look into database optimization to see what is actually happening with the `$item->entity` reference, and put an index on the joins/where statements but I am not very confident that is the best way.

Comment: +1 for caching. I usually do not worry about database queries and loading entities too much, because there is much more performance to gain in caching. Especially Drupal 8 has a very sophisticated caching system. If you add the appropriate cache tags to whatever you're caching, you shouldn't even have to invalidate your cache when nodes are updated or inserted; Drupal will take care of it. I highly recommend learning about Drupal 8 cacheability metadata if you haven't already.